# Comma-separated jQuery selectors performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Please advise which way using selectors in jQuery is faster:

```
$('.class1, .class2').html('');
```

or

```
$('.class1').html('');
$('.class2').html('');
```

Comment: Use [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/)....

Comment: I thought there are some tests ready before

Comment: http://jsperf.com/sepeared-selectoxred -- Here ya go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms [performance they seems to be almost same](http://jsperf.com/multiple-vs-separate-selector)(7-8%), but in terms of maintainability the first method will be better since there is no duplication of code

Answer (score 1):

[check Performance](http://jsperf.com/single-selector-or-multiple)

Single `$('.class1, .class2').html('');` better as

1. no duplication of code
2. jQuery constructor is called only once which makes it little fast.(+3-4%)