# Comma-Separated jQuery Performance with selector and context

Tags: jquery, performance

Is there a performance difference between:

```
$("#divId :input")
```

and

```
$("#divId").find(":input")
```

and

```
$(":input", "#divId")
```

The last variation is described here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

(Not quite the same as [Comma-separated jQuery selectors performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972010/comma-separated-jquery-selectors-performance))

Comment: According to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context): `Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" ).` According to [this test](https://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/9), `find()` looks faster than the descendant selector.

Comment: It should be noted that the `children()` option is not guarenteed to be a 1:1 result set of the first two operations in the test. @showdev

Comment: @showdev Very interesting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The selectors that start by selecting an id is the fastest, for two reasons:

1. JQuery uses the native methods to grap the ids.
2. When you use an id as selector, it heavily reduces the match (normally only one will be returned). That Means it only has to filter one (or a few elements) with your ':input' Query. The smaller matches the faster.

The difference between first and second option will be minimal.

Comment: But don't all three start with an id selector?

Comment: @showdev pointed out above that $(":input", "#divId") is equivalent to $("#divId").find(":input") which I did not know.  Note that this is (obviously) not the same as $(":input #divId")

Comment: Forget my last comment, they are the same.